# How to enable timer0 interrupt in atmega328p?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega32

I'm trying to make a blinking led with an atmega328p using the timer0 interrupt.

It's a pretty basic thing but Microchip Studio gives me this:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped=======
```

How to solve this issue? The code is attached below:

```c
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
    
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
    
int main(void)
{
  //define inputs and outputs
  DDRC = (1<<DDC4); // portc4 as output
  TCNT0 = 0x00;
  TCCR0A = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = (1<<CS00) | (1<<CS01);
  TIMSK0 = (1<<TOIE0);
  sei(); // set global interrupts
  while (1) 
  {
    PORTC4 |= (1<<PORTC4);
  }
}
    
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
  TCNT0 = 0x00;
  PORTC &= ~(1<<PORTC4);    
}
```

Comment: Please find and add the actual error message, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: microchip studio doesn't give me the error message or i can't get. so, could you tell me how to get the error message?

Comment: My guess is `#define F_CPU 1000000UL` should be before `#include<util/delay.h>`.

Comment: i tried this out and it didn't work.

Comment: Goto Options->Projects->Build&Run and check if "project build output verbosity" is set to "Detailed" or "Diagnostic". But AFAIK it should even show a proper error message on lower settings.

Comment: https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/3055591#comment-3055591

Comment: I would guess, the failure is related to `PORTC4 |= (1<<PORTC4);`. You can not assign to an integer literal. ... Oh, and I doubt, you'll see the LED really blink with your eyes ... Why don't you just toggle the pin in the interrupt, instead of always turning the LED on in the main while loop?

Comment: @MikeCAT : except that code does not appear to rely on anything likely to be declared or defined in in delay.h it is redundant. `F_CPU ` itself is unused.

Comment: @Yunnosch His environment is perfect capable.  He just needs to learn to use it.  I've been using Studio for over a decade.  And the FCPU doesn't belong there, that's been deprecated for almost a decade, too.  It belongs in environment settings.

Comment: @TomServo Yeah, I thought so. And I have to admit that I missed the part where OP changes from "impossible" to "help me find it", which is of course the right way to go about this. Sorry Sayed Omar.

Answer (score 0):

Some things corrected, maybe this helps:

```c
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
    // TCNT0 = 0x00;  // Not necessary, it is done by hardware
    PORTC = ~(1<<PINC4);
}

int main(void)
{
    //define inputs and outputs
    DDRC = (1<<PINC4);
    
    // TCNT0 = 0x00;    // Autoset to zero after initialisation
    // TCCR0A = 0x00;   // Autoset at startup
    
    // Timer 0
    // Mode: Overflow, Interrupt
    // Prescaler: /64
    TCCR0B = (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00);
    TIMSK0 = (1<<TOIE0);
    
    sei(); // set global interrupts
    
    while (1)
    {
        // PORTC |= (1<<PINC4); // is done in interrupt
    }
}
```

> `Build succeeded.`

> `========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`